# How to find if text on UILabel will be suffixed with "..."?

Tags: objective-c, ios

How to find if text on UILabel will be suffixed with "..."?

Comment: You mean if the text set to an object (eg, UILabel) gets truncated; check out the lineBreakMode property and adjust accordingly. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/lineBreakMode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a uilabel will be shrinked or not using this:

```
CGSize stringSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font];
if (stringSize.width > label.frame.size.width) {



}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
if([label.text hasSuffix:@"..."])
{
   //has suffix.
}
```

Okay, if you want to check if the string is greater the label's width do something like this:

```
CGSize size = [someString sizeWithFont:label.font
                           constrainedToSize:label.frame.size
                               lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
if(size.width > label.frame.size.width)
{
     //string is greater than label
}
```

Comment: You must be doing something wrong because this is the standard why to see if text has a `suffix` or not.

Comment: when you set bigger text than a uilabel width, the uilabel automatically shrinks itself and adds "...", this is for presentation purpose label.text does not contain "...". that's why above solution didn't work at all!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the UIKit NSString Additions they add methods for finding out how much space a string will take for a given font
[NSString UIKit Additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html)